# Unable to scroll up to the top of a menu from a button click - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Question Background:**

I am using Jasny Bootstrap's Reveal Menu. A demo can be found here:

http://codepen.io/michaelbowlin/pen/lDqpm

**The Issue:**

Within my reveal menu I have a form that requires the revealed panel to be scrolled up to the top when the button is either opened or closed from a click. The following shows the menu panel revealed with the scroll bar active:

[image]

The following is the menu markup for the menu:

```
<div class="navmenu navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-left" id="updateMenu">
    //*********Form**********
</div>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <button id="menuBtn" type="button" ng-click="ScrollUp()" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-recalc="false" data-target=".navmenu" data-canvas=".canvas">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

I have added a `ng-click` directive on the `Button` markup and give this the ID of `updateMenu`. This calls a function named ScrollUp() on the $scope object on the UpdateController, as shown:

```
app.controller('UpdateController', function ($scope, $timeout, $location,   $anchorScroll, $window, searchService) {
            $scope.ScrollUp = function () {

            $location.hash('#updateMenu');

            $anchorScroll();
        }
    }
```

Currently this does not work. I have also tried the following functionality which does not work:

```
    app.controller('UpdateController', function ($scope, $timeout, $location,   $anchorScroll, $window, searchService) {

               $scope.ScrollUp = function () {

              $window.scrollTo(0, angular.element('#updateMenu').offsetTop);
    }

}
```

**How can I scroll up to the top of the revealed menu when the user clicks the button `updateMenu`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve the desired effect by setting the element's [scrollTop property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) to 0. Using the following code for your `ScrollUp` function should allow for the menu to jump back to it's starting point.

```
$scope.ScrollUp = function () {
  document.getElementById('updateMenu').scrollTop = 0;
}
```

[Codepen sandbox included here.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NAyKYY)

Answer (score 0):

Both of your current implementations that you posted are trying to scroll the main webpage to the top. The way I understand it is you want to scroll the menu to the top when they open or close the menu.

**Javascript**

```
$scope.ScrollUp = function () {
  document.getElementById('updateMenu').scrollTop = 0;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$scope.ScrollUp = function () {
  $("#updateMenu").scrollTop();
}
```

**jQuery with animation**

```
$scope.ScrollUp = function () {
  $('#updateMenu').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow', function () {
      alert("reached top");
  });
}
```

**AngularJs**

If you want to do it the AngularJS way there is a similar question here:
[Scroll to top of div in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040985/scroll-to-top-of-div-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

It should work with [`$anchorScroll`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll).

But you can also use its [`yOffset`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll.yOffset) property to specify a vertical scroll-offset (either fixed or dynamic).

In order for yOffset to work properly, **scrolling should take place on the document's root and not some child element**.